# Inheriting the template of an extended base component

Tags: angular

Is it possible to inherit the template of an extended base component? Like in my case, I have a ChildComponent which is extended from BaseComponent like below:

```js
@Component({ selector: 'lib-base', template: '<div>Base Template</div>' )}
export class BaseComponent {
}


@Component({ selector: 'lib-child', template: '<lib-base></lib-base><div>Child Template</div>' )}
export class ChildComponent extends BaseComponent {
}
```

However, following the above pattern results in BaseComponent being instantiated twice.
Since, I am very much new to Angular, i am not familiar with how to achieve the above case without duplicating BaseComponent.

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot include lib-child inside of lib-base? Angular provides a way for you to load components dynamically, but its a more advanced approach than simply including a component nested inside of a component: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: @shadowfox476 In the actual application code, we have core code logics within BaseComponent which is needed by ChildComponent during initialisation. Also, the BaseComponent is made up of several sub common components (moreover like a common template) which needs to be rendered in all inherited Child Components's template. Hence, had to follow the above approach instead of dynamic component loader.